# Where are the supposed ruins of Lon Lon Ranch?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I've seen an image around, but can't find it anymore.

It showed that somewhere in *Breath of the Wild*, there were the ruins of Lon Lon Ranch, more particularly the ring around which you race to get Epona.

I've ran around Hyrule quite a lot, but never stumbled on it. Does anybody know where it is?

Comment: head southeast from Hyrule Castle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This article](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/lon-lon-ranch-breath-wild-location-ocarina-time-easter-egg-hidden-central-hyrule-589531) gives directions on where you can find what appears to be the ruins of Lon Lon Ranch.

> Open your Hyrule Field Map and look for the “Ranch Ruins” near Hyrule Field Tower. Avoid the Guardian that’s there waiting to end your life and you’ll end up in a burnt down village that looks strangely familiar.

[Here's a video that shows the location, as well.](https://youtu.be/tytX6sQRcCE)

Comment: Aw! That video's so cute.